# How to Send Text in an UIInputViewController

Tags: ios

so I've got the following code to insert text:

```
func insert(text: String) {
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(text)
}
```

But how do I actually get it to send to the chat window?

Comment: Can you provide more informations ? What are you actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Jack Robson, If you mean to access the complete text entered, then my answer may help

Comment: @JackRobson, I have some doubts. 1) chat window - what are you referring to? 2) is this UIInputViewController part of an app or an app extension? Can you please clarify so that I can understand the problem better and help you

Comment: Say for example, I am writing in WhatsApp with my custom keyboard extension. Is it possible to send a message without clicking the WhatsApp send button?

Comment: @JackRobson, No. It is not possible at all. You only have limited control over keyboard. You don't  have control over your host app. You can only play with text like deleting and inserting it. Apart from that, you don't have control over the host app like sending a text message.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to access all the text entered in the `UIInputViewController`, the following code may help:

```
var totalText = "" // complete text entered

if let before: String = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput {
   totalText += before
}

if let after: String = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput {
   totalText += after
}
```

Now that you have complete text entered, you can send it to chat window. There are some limitations here which I can share if this is what you're looking for. Please let me know

**Edit**

To send text to `whatsapp`, you need to press `send button` which is `outside` the `custom keyboard extension`. If you want to enter text into the `UITextView` of `whatsapp`, it is pretty straightforward to do so. But, the `custom keyboard extension` can't control the send button of `whatsapp`

Comment: Yeh I'm looking to send it to the chat window